# Unable to build and debug my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app with .NET Standard 2.0 class libraries

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview 2 project that has a few .NET Standard 2.0 libraries.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.7 Preview 6.

I have to use Preview version of VS because ASP.NET Core 2.1 is in preview as well and requires the preview version of VS.

Everytime I try to debug, I'm getting errors that read:

> Metadata file 'C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.MyClassLibraryProject\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyProject.MyClassLibraryProject.dll'
>   could not be found

All of the projects are in the same folder for the solution.

I just rebuilt my Windows 10 PC and installed everything fresh. I was having some issues building this project in VS before but not this particular error. The problem before was that I could build and debug the solution but I couldn't publish it to Azure for `x64`. I'd made the Visual Studio team aware of the issue but they couldn't come up with any answers so I decided to clean up the PC and start fresh. Now, I'm having this new issue!

I also want to mention that up until a few minutes ago, I could actually build and debug the solution but I had to do a `Build Solution`. If I did a `Rebuild Solution`, I'd get errors indicating missing references to my class library projects. This worked for a while but I then realized that even in `debug` mode, I couldn't hit my break points. So I decided to do a `Clean Solution` and ever since I'm now getting this new error and I just can't build or debug my solution.

In the `csproj` file for the ASP.NET Core 2.1 project, I see these entries. Do I need them?

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
   <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
   <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
   <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
   <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: I've seen a similar issue to yours where a `Clean`, `Rebuild Solution` and delete of the obj and bin folder didn't fix any thing. The solution was to right click on the project and click `Build Project` for each project in the solution. The `Rebuild Solution` didn't build some projects even though they were set to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the latest **Visual Studio 2017 15.7** Final with .NET Core 2.1 RC1. It solves my issue on version VS2017 15.7 Preview 4 with .NET Core 2.1 Preview 2.

Answer (score 0):

One of the quirks of VS. Using VS 2017, I had the same issue where all the references were showing like they were unavailable. Running "Restore Nuget Packages" didn't help.
Out of curiosity, I picked one of the projects having the problem, checked Properties of the project, and changed the Target framework from .Net Standard 2.0 down to 1.6. Saved, then changed it back to 2.0, and all the warnings across the Solution updated themselves, and the missing SDK and NuGet references were "found". Built immediately.